# DBLookupComboBox and DBGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I have an Access database that contains three tables (Specialty Table, Table Section and Trainee Table). Each specialty has several sections and each section contains several trainees. I want to put two DBLookupComboBox, the first to choose the specialty and the second to display only sections of the chosen specialty.
What I want to realize is that when I choose a specialty in the first DBLookupComboBox, the second DBLookupComboBox only displays sections that belong to that specialty. And after I have chosen a Section of the second DBLookupComboBox, it will show me only trainees in that section in a DBGrid.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, which you should be able to work out for yourself - if not then what you need is a tutorial, and SO isn't a site for tutorials, so try googling for one.

Comment: Did you not ask the exactly same question yesterday? Comments to your yesterday post asked you to spell out your specific question. Now you still only express what you want to do, and by all means, just go ahead. SO is not a code writing service, iow we will not write your work for you. But we will help you if you just can point at the difficulty you have. Clear and specific questions, please.

Comment: Please read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question, **especially** [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and all linked docs.

Answer (score 0):

You should place a `TFDQuery` and a `TDataSource` for each `ComboBox`. Let's say qry is the Query and ds is the Datasource:

- `qrySpeciality` and `dsSpeciality`;
- `qrySection` and `dsSection`;

**Step 1.**

Make the proper connections for both situations, `DataSource` connects to the `Query` and the `ComboBox` connects to the `DataSource`.

**Step 2.**

When the form starts in the `FormCreate` event you should use the first to query the speciality table in your database and display it in your first `ComboBox`.

**Step 3.**

Each time your  first `ComboBox` changes you want to show sections from that given speciality. Make your query in your section table inside the `onDataChange` method of the `dsSpeciality`. This method is executed whenever the data is change in the `DataSource`, this means when you select a new item in the `ComboBox` of the specialities.